# Remove "-" from submitted URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a url on my site http://sainthelenaisland.info/highknollfort.htm which people keep submitting as http://sainthelenaisland.info/high-knoll-fort.htm so they get an error. There are many other pages on the site that have the same problem. My suggested Solution - use mod rewrite to remove the hyphens (I have no pages with intended hyphens so this won't cause a problem ). I tried RewriteRule ([^\-]*)\-(.*) $1$2 but it didn't work. I based this on RewriteRule ([^E]*)E(.*) $1e$2 (upper to lowercase) but I don't understand mod rewrite enough to know how to fix it or an alternative way to achieve the result. All the other examples I can find replace something with something else.  How do I replace something with nothing? HELP!